# knockout.js observable array push delay on each item

Tags: javascript, arrays, knockout.js, css-animations

I have an array that pushes items into an interface.  Right now all items show up at once with a little animation with opacity.  However, I want each to show up one by one with a small delay.  As if they are coming in right after each other.

However, everything I try it seems they still show up at the same time.  I used `rate limit` but that didnt seem to help. Below is my array and I am using `splice`.  I even used a `setTimeout` within the foreach.

```
 self.plays = ko.observableArray([]);

        self.update = function (period) {
             period.Plays.forEach(function (p, index) {
                        self.plays.splice(0, 0, p);
                    });
        };
```

**CSS**

```
.play-by-plays .play.flash,
    .line-scores .line-period.flash {
        transition: color 1s ease;
    }

    .play-by-plays .play,
    .line-scores .line-period {
        transition: color 1s ease;
    }
```

Comment: Are you using `foreach` for the DOM manipulation? If yes, go through the last part of the `foreach` documentation. It could be of use.
http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/foreach-binding.html

Comment: Well I am already doing animation with CSS, that is working fine.  However, I want a delay of when each item appears, so it looks like they are pushed not at the same time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You said you tried `setTimeout`. Did you try like this?

```js
function ViewModel(){
  var self = this;
  self.plays = ko.observableArray();

  self.Periods = [{'letter':'a'},{'letter':'b'},{'letter':'c'}];

  self.update = function(){
    var counter = 0;
    self.Periods.forEach(function(letter){
      setTimeout(function(){
        self.plays.unshift(letter);
      }, counter);
      counter += 500;
    });
  };
  
  self.update();
}

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
<div data-bind="foreach: plays">
  <span data-bind="text: letter"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: The items need to be pushed at the start of the list.

Comment: For that you need to use `unshift`. I've updated my fiddle.

Comment: @MikeFlynn does that help?